# JavaScript regex on dates, dashes etc

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following possible strings:

```
01/01/2013

< 01/01/2013

> 01/01/2013

< 01/01/2013 - 01/01/2013

> 01/01/2013 - 01/01/2013

> 01/01/2013 - < 01/01/2013

> 01/01/2013 - > 01/01/2013

< 01/01/2013 - < 01/01/2013

< 01/01/2013 - > 01/01/2013

01/01/2013 - 01/01/2013
```

These are all filters that can be applied to search for specific dates. What I want to do is split the string into chunks that can be managed by my code.

So for example:

`var filter = '> 01/01/2013 - < 01/01/2013'`

```
var string1 = '>';
var string2 = '01/01/2013';
var string3 = '<';
var string4 = '01/01/2013';
```

So string1 would be the first angled bracket it can find. String2 would always be the second date it could find. And string3 the next angled bracket. And finally string4 the next date it could find.

I've had a look at various examples, and so far have the following:

```
var string1 = filter.split([\<>]);
var string2 = filter.split(^(0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)\d\d$.);
var string3 = filter.split([\<>]);
var string4 = filter.split(^(0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)\d\d$.);
```

But I'm not sure this is the best way to achieve what I want. Does anyone have any examples or suggestions for handling this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get all your strings in an array with

```
var strings = filter.match(/^\s*(<|>)?\s*(\d\d\/\d\d\/\d{4})\s*\-?\s*(<|>)?\s*(\d\d\/\d\d\/\d{4})?\s*$/).slice(1);
```

This regex ensures the order (if a `<` or `>` is missing, there's a `undefined` in the array).

For example :

`'> 01/01/2013 - < 01/01/2013'` gives `[">", "01/01/2013", "<", "01/01/2013"]`

`'> 01/01/2013'` gives `[">", "01/01/2013", undefined, undefined]`

`'01/01/2013 - 01/01/2013'` gives `[undefined, "01/01/2013", undefined, "01/01/2013"]`

Comment: @Mr_Green well, yes. It depends if the goal is also to validate.

Comment: @Mr_Green In fact there's a problem with your regex : it doesn't ensure the position of strings in the array if the < and > are missing.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just remove all the dashes and then split at the space character?

```
filter = filter.replace("- ", "");
strings = filter.split(" ");
```

Comment: Not sure but `\s` seems better here as there seems to be enter in strings.